# How to validate a date in MySQL that also has a date in alphanumeric

Tags: mysql, sql

I basically have a table in which the users have inputted their Date of birth in the format.

DAY-MONTH-YEAR (01-Dec-2012)

The data in the table has mixed errors with some people having the that field empty, others have just the words 'DAY-MONTH-YEAR' other having '--', other '' and others just have '02-12-YEAR' and other have '--1985'. I know... terrible

I am trying to now filter so that I only get in my query people  that only inputted the full DoB in the correct format.

my REGEXP is not great... and i was wondering if anyone could help me with on how to validate the date in MySQL. I could achieve this easily in PHP but trying to keep this process in the model of my application.

```
SELECT m_dob FROM `mariners` WHERE m_dob IS NOT NULL AND m_dob != '' and m_dob != 'Day-Month-Year' AND m_dob != '--' AND m_dob REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{4}$';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save yourself from the pain of using regular expressions and just call upon MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function instead:

```
SELECT m_dob FROM mariners WHERE STR_TO_DATE(m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL
```

As documented in the manual:

> If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from ***`str`*** is illegal, [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) returns `NULL` and produces a warning.

---

#### UPDATE

As noted in your comment, there are some circumstances in which [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) can return a zero date.  To avoid this, either:

- enable the [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) SQL mode:

  ```
  SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE'
  ```
- or else use another function such as [`TO_DAYS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) to verify the date's validity:

  ```
  SELECT m_dob
  FROM   mariners
  WHERE  TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y')) IS NOT NULL
  ```

I do not recommend manually trying to capture all instances of input dates that might give rise to a zero date, as it is quite possible that some other corner cases will get overlooked.

Comment: Thank you. Thats easier that all that fancy regular expression match. although that doesn't filter the mentioned case of the ones that have are empty with a space meaning = ' '. The correct query is: Please amend your answer `SELECT m_dob FROM mariners WHERE STR_TO_DATE(m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL AND m_dob != ''`